# Argument passed into graphql mutation is always undefined

Tags: node.js, graphql

Learning graphql, cannot get mutation to work yet, get lost on the online examples.

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import { graphqlHTTP } from 'express-graphql'
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema'

const app = express()
const port = 4000

// In-memory data store
const data = {
  warriors: [
    { id: '001', name: 'Jaime' },
    { id: '002', name: 'Jorah' },
  ],
}

// Schema
const typeDefs = `
type Warrior {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  warriors: [Warrior]
}

type Mutation {
  addUser(name: String!): Warrior!
}
`

// Resolver for warriors
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    warriors: (obj, args, context) => context.warriors,
  },
  Mutation: {
    //addUser: (parent: unknown, args: {name: String}) => {
    addUser: (name) => {
      console.log('------ 1 ----------');
      const id = String(data.warriors.length + 1);
      const warrior = {id, name};
      console.dir(warrior);
      console.log('------ 3 ----------');
      data.warriors.push(warrior);
      return data.warriros;
    },
  },
}

const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// Entrypoint
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: executableSchema,
    context: data,
    graphiql: true,
  })
)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running a server at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

in http://localhost:4000/graphql
i tried to run this, but the name passed in is always undefined

```
    mutation {
      addUser(name: "ccc") {
       id   
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions pls ? Thx !

---

Updated answer from below

```
// Resolver for warriors
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    warriors: (obj, args, context) => context.warriors,
  },
  Mutation: {
    addUser: (_, {name}) => {
      const id = String(data.warriors.length + 1);
      const warrior = {id, name};
      data.warriors.push(warrior);
      return warrior;
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deconstruct the args to get your `name` variable. Right now you are treating the `parent` argument of the mutation as `name` and the parent arg is undefined.
The function signature is:

```
myMutation: (parent,args,context,info) =>
```

So try:

```
Mutation: {
    addUser: (_, { name }) => {
      const id = String(data.warriors.length + 1);
      const warrior = {id, name};
      data.warriors.push(warrior);
      return warrior;
    },
}
```

Also your mutation expects a single `Warrior` type as a result, not the whole array.

Comment: Hi Michel, i can see mutation working for the 1st time, very excited, was lost on the different examples/packages. Thx so much !